# AlarmManger with show notification on specific time

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm

I have the following code (abbreviated to the relevant part). If I set the alarm manger on a specific time and when this time comes the notification doesn't show up. I want to set date like sun-mon-tue.

**`Code Snippet :`**

```
public class service extends Service {

    private int Period_You_Want_in_MilliSecond = 30 * 1000;
    Calendar calender ;
    SimpleDateFormat format ;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        DataBase DB=new DataBase(this);
        //get row from database where id=1
        final CourseClass C=DB.getCousre(1);

        calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Handler h = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                String current_time = format.format(calender.getTime());
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+current_time,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //check if the row reterned if filed name has data lenght>0 return True
                if(C.getName().length()>0){
                    if(current_time.equals("01:24 PM")){
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIMER",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        show_notification();

                    }
                }
                h.postDelayed(this,Period_You_Want_in_MilliSecond);
            }
        };      


        h.post(r);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Comment: and here is my create notification method

public void show_notification(){
  
  NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Notification noti = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Update !!!", 0);
  
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), reciever.class);
  PendingIntent Pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(service.this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  noti .defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
  noti.setLatestEventInfo(service.this, "My APP", "New Update is found",Pintent);

  manager.notify(1, noti);
    
 }

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the AlarmManager, you are using a Handler.
Take a look at [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Comment: i want my program on specifc time ex : 5:10 PM 
make a notification ! 
so i used caleneder

Comment: Again, you should use the AlarmManager for that. Currently you are using you Handler h.